# SignalR : Group client count goes below zero

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

I have several pages which use SignalR. There are 3 groups on each page.
I tried to keep database record of client count for each group.
Problem is that the client count in rooms becomes a negative number.

Database table looks like this :
GroupName nvarchar(10) PK,
Count int not null

In my Hub class I use OnConnected() and OnDisconnected() to control the count.

```
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string mAsset1 = Context.QueryString["asset1"];
        string mAsset2 = Context.QueryString["asset2"];

        string body = "{0}/{1}";
        string groupName = string.Format(body, mAsset1, mAsset2);

        JoinRoom(groupName);

        SignalRClientCountCrud.AddToClientCounter(groupName); //UPDATING DATABASE

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stop)
    {
        string mAsset1 = Context.QueryString["asset1"];
        string mAsset2 = Context.QueryString["asset2"];

        string body = "{0}/{1}";
        string groupName= string.Format(body, mAsset1, mAsset2);
        
        SignalRClientCountCrud.RemoveFromClientCounter(groupName); //UPDATING DATABASE

        return base.OnDisconnected(stop);
    }
    public Task JoinRoom(string groupName)
    {
        Task result = Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        return result;
    }
```

Adding and removing client count from Database (The methods I am calling in Hub class)

```
    public static void AddToClientCounter(string roomName)
    {
        List<string> rooms = GetRooms(roomName);
        using (DatabaseEntities db = DbManager.Get())
        {
            foreach (string room in rooms)
            {
                SignalRClientCount group = db.SignalRClientCounts.Where(c => c.GroupName == room).FirstOrDefault();
                if (group != null)
                {
                    group.ClientCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    SignalRClientCount signalRGroupCount = new SignalRClientCount();
                    signalRGroupCount.GroupName = room;
                    signalRGroupCount.ClientCount = 1;
                    db.SignalRClientCounts.Add(signalRGroupCount);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void RemoveFromClientCounter(string roomName)
    {
        List<string> rooms = GetRooms(roomName);

        using (DatabaseEntities db = DbManager.Get())
        {
            foreach (string room in rooms)
            {
                SignalRClientCount group = db.SignalRClientCounts.Where(c => c.GroupName == room).FirstOrDefault();
                if (group != null)
                {
                    group.ClientCount--;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Sometimes, in database group X will have count of -5.